# Split Text from transcript to word table (word macro)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a transcript with (in every line) a time stamp, name and text (separate by normal spaces). Looks like this:

> 00:00 Name Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
>   sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
>   aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et

00:00 = time stamp

Name = name

everything else = text

---

I have to paste this into a Word table.

The table looks like this:

[image]

Is there a possibility to automate that step?

Comment: I work on MS Word 2016 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Name` is a single word (no spaces) and each line is a paragraph, you could Find/Replace to create tab characters between fields. In the `Find` dialog select `Use wildcards`. For `Find what:` use:

```
([0:9]{2}:[0:9]{2}) (<[! ]@>) ([!^13]@)^13
```

and for `Replace with:` use:

```
\1^t\2^t\3^p
```

Then `00:00 Name Lorem ipsum ...` becomes `00:00<TAB>Name<TAB>Lorem ipsum ...`

Once the text is tab-delimited, use Word's `Convert Text to Table ...` feature to get a 3-column table.

Hope that helps